# Error boundary doesn't catch error in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo, react-error-boundary

I would like to add an error boundary to an Expo app. The app has been built with `eas build --platform android --profile development --local`, and runs in an Android emulator thanks to `expo-dev-client`.

Unfortunately, when throwing an error on purpose, the app crashes without letting the error boundary do its job.

Here is the error-boundary code:

```js
import React from "react";
import FallbackComponent from "./fallback";

type Props = {
  children: Node;
  onError?: Function;
};

type State = { error: Error | null };

class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  state: State = { error: null };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error: Error): State {
    return { error };
  }

  render(): React.ReactNode {
    return this.state.error ? <FallbackComponent /> : this.props.children;
  }
}

export default ErrorBoundary;
```

it's used as such in `app.tsx`:

```js
    <ErrorBoundary>
      <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <I18nProvider languages={{ en, fr }} defaultLanguage="en">
          <NavigationContainer theme={theme}>
            <BottomTabsNavigator />
          </NavigationContainer>
        </I18nProvider>
      </View>
    </ErrorBoundary>
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to also add a componentDidCatch method to see if anything happens in that one.

```
componentDidCatch(error, info) {
    console.warn('error caught in boundary ', error); 
    console.warn('error info  caught in boundary ', info); 
    });
    this.setState({ hasError: true, error, info });
  }
```

Comment: Nice idea, but it doesn't work. The error is not caught.

Comment: @DoneDeal0 Then try moving the errorBoundary component inside your NavigationContainer that is the setup I have and that works fine

Comment: still doesn't work :(.

Comment: Are you sure that your class does not need a constructor?

Comment: Are you able to log the error in componentDidCatch?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [`react-native-exception-handler`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-exception-handler) and `Expo`. We are currently using this both in the `Expo Go` app as well as with production builds through `eas build`.

Run:

```
yarn add react-native-exception-handler
```

Then, in your `index.js` file, add the following code:

```
import { setJSExceptionHandler } from "react-native-exception-handler";

const exceptionhandler = (error, isFatal) => {
  // your error handler function
  console.log({ error, isFatal });
};
setJSExceptionHandler(exceptionhandler, true);
```

Since this code involves native code and linking, it might autogenerate an `android/` and `ios/` folder in your Expo project even if you are developing with `Expo Go`. If you want to exclude these files from your production build, you can add them to a `.easignore` or call `rm -rf <ios | android>`

*Note: Your code above is failing because `getDerivedStateFromError` generally catches rendering errors from components and doesn't handle cases like event handlers, async code, etc. You can learn more about the limitations [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html).